# Controls don't work after update panel refresh

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm building a table using a asp:Repeater that is inside an UpdatePanel. A column of this table contains some buttons. When these buttons get pressed, there is a partial refresh (i think..) of the UpdatePanel.

What is strange is that some OTHER buttons that are outside and at the top of the table inside another UpdatePanel stop working.

They works perfectly if i don't click the buttons in the repeater. Otherwise they seem to not respond to click event anymore.

A clarification: The refresh button keep working. But even the simple checkbox does not work anymore.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="containerNotificationCenterDx">
                <!-- Contains the five buttons that stop working -->
                <div id="containerNotificationFilter">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpPnlBAction" UpdateMode="Conditional" ClientIDMode="static">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="col11" style="padding-left: 10px">
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="cbSelectAllNotify" runat="server" CssClass="clickableRight" OnCheckedChanged="SelectAllNotify_CheckedChanged"
                                    AutoPostBack="true" />
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="IndexImgRefreshCM" OnClick="IndexImgRefreshCM_OnClick" CssClass="clickableRight">
                                    <i class="fa fa-refresh"></i> <!-- this always works -->
                                </asp:LinkButton>                            
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="IndexImgAddFilterCM" OnClientClick="return ajaxModalPopupAddFilterNotificationCenter();" CssClass="clickableRight">
                                    <span id="spanAddFilter">
                                        <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="IndexImgRemoveFilterCM" OnClick="IndexImgRemoveFilter_OnClick" Enabled="false" CssClass="clickableRight">
                                    <span id="spanRemoveFilter">
                                        <i class="fa fa-filter"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="IndexImgExportCM" OnClientClick="return ajaxModalPopupExportDati();" CssClass="clickableRight">
                                    <i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>
                                </asp:LinkButton>                                    
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="IndexImgSmistaCM" OnClick="IndexImgSmista_OnClick" CssClass="clickableRight">
                                    <span id="spanSmista">
                                        <i class="fa fa-file-o"></i>
                                        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>
                                    </span>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="IndexImgDeleteCM" OnClick="IndexImgRemove_OnClick" CssClass="clickableRight">
                                    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                </asp:LinkButton>
                            </div>
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>                    
                <!-- Main notifications container -->
                <div id="containerListNotify" style="padding-left: 5px;">
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelRepListNotify" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ClientIDMode="Static">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <!-- DEFINISCE LA STRUTTURA DELLE NOTIFICHE -->
                            <asp:Repeater ID="repListNotify" runat="server" OnItemCommand="RepListNotify_ItemCommand"
                                OnItemDataBound="RepListNotify_ItemCreated">
                                <HeaderTemplate>
                                    <table id="tableCentroMessaggi" class="table table-hover">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr id="HeaderMessaggi">
                                                <th>                                                   
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="docFascCol"  Text='<%#this.getDocFascColText() %>' />
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="dataCol"  Text='<%#this.getDataColText() %>' />
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="eventCol"  Text='<%#this.getEventColText() %>' />
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="fromCol"  Text='<%#this.getSenderColText() %>' />
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="objDescCol"  Text='<%#this.getObjDescColText() %>' />
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="tipologyCol"  Text='<%#this.getTipologyColText() %>' />
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="senderCol"  Text='<%#this.getEmailColText() %>' />
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="noteCol"  Text='<%#this.getNoteColText() %>' />
                                                </th>
                                                <th>
                                                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="actionsCol"  Text='<%#this.getActionsColText() %>' />
                                                </th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                </HeaderTemplate>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <tr id="messageRow" runat="server">
                                        <td id="messageDetails">
                                            <div>
                                                <!-- checkbox rimozione notifica -->
                                                <asp:CheckBox ID="IndexChkRemoveNotify" CssClass="clickableLeftN" runat="server" />
                                                <!-- icona dettagli documento/fascicolo -->
                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="IndexImgDetailsDocument" CommandName="ViewDetailsDocument" CssClass="clickableRight">
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                                <!-- id -->
                                                <br />
                                                <div class="notifyField">
                                                    <span class="noLink">
                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="lblNotifyLink" runat="server" Text='<%#this.getLabelFieldLink((NttDataWA.DocsPaWR.Notification) Container.DataItem) %>' CommandName="viewLinkObject" OnClientClick="disallowOpHome('Content2');">
                                                        </asp:LinkButton>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>

                                        <td id="date">
                                            <asp:Label ID="IndexLblDate" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DTA_EVENT") %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>

                                        <td id="mexEvent">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# GetEvent((NttDataWA.DocsPaWR.Notification) Container.DataItem) %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>

                                        <td id="mexSender">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# GetSource((NttDataWA.DocsPaWR.Notification) Container.DataItem) %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>

                                        <td id="objDescription">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# GetObjDesc((NttDataWA.DocsPaWR.Notification) Container.DataItem) %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>

                                        <td id="tipology">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# GetData((NttDataWA.DocsPaWR.Notification) Container.DataItem, Column.Tipology) %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>

                                        <td id="mittente">
                                            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# GetData((NttDataWA.DocsPaWR.Notification) Container.DataItem, Column.Sender) %>'></asp:Label>
                                        </td>

                                        <td id="note">
                                            <div id="containerNoteNotify" runat="server">
                                                <div class="fieldNotesHome">
                                                    <div class="fieldNotesHomeBt">
                                                        <div class="weight">
                                                            <asp:Label ID="lblNotes" Text='<%$ localizeByText:IndexLblNotes%>' runat="server"
                                                                Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div style="padding-top: 30px; padding-left: 55px;">
                                                            <cc1:CustomTextArea ID="txtNoteNotify" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" ClientIDMode="Static"
                                                                CssClass="homeNotes">
                                                            </cc1:CustomTextArea>
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div style="text-align: right;">
                                                            <asp:Button ID="litSaveNotes" Text='<%$ localizeByText:IndexLitSaveNotes%>' CommandName="SaveNotesNotify"
                                                                runat="server" CssClass="buttonNotes" ImageAlign="Right"></asp:Button>
                                                            <asp:Button ID="litRemoveNotes" Text='<%$ localizeByText:IndexLitRemoveNotes%>' CommandName="RemoveNotesNotify"
                                                                runat="server" CssClass="buttonNotes" ImageAlign="Right"></asp:Button>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <!-- these buttons generate the issue -->
                                        <td id="actionsButtons">
                                            <div id="actionsButtonsContainer">
                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnTypeDocCM" CommandName="ViewDocument" CssClass="clickableLeft"
                                                    ToolTip='<%$ localizeByText:IndexBtnTypeDocTooltip%>'>
                                                        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnSignatureDetails" CommandName="SignatureDetails" CssClass="clickable"
                                                    ToolTip='<%$ localizeByText:DocumentSignatureDetails%>' Visible="false">
                                                        <i class="dettaglioFirma">&#xe800;</i>
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="IndexImgAdd" CommandName="AddNote" CssClass="clickableLeft"
                                                    Visible='<%#GetEnableNote() %>'>
                                                        <span class="fa-stack">
                                                            <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-stack-2x"></i>
                                                            <i class="fa fa-plus fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                                        </span>
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="IndexImgRemoveNotify" CommandName="RemoveNotify" CssClass="clickableRight">
                                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                                </asp:LinkButton>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="NotifyId" Value='<%# Bind("ID_NOTIFY") %>' />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                                <FooterTemplate>
                                    </tbody>   
                                    </table>                                     
                                </FooterTemplate>
                            </asp:Repeater>
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="grid_rowindex" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenRemoveNotifications" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenRemoveNotification" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="grid_pageindex" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
                <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPnlGridIndexes" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <div id="navHome">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="plcNavigator" runat="server" />
                        </div>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                </asp:UpdatePanel>
            </div>
```

I don't get any error.

**Update:** All the controls in the "UpPnlBAction" UpdatePanel don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in update panel `ChildrenAsTriggers ="false"` then see

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.childrenastriggers(v=vs.110).aspx

Check if this solves your problem or not